# Gnucash brokerage account with multiple stocks

Tags: stocks, gnucash, accounts

GNUCash setup is driving me nuts.  Most accounting software tools allow you to create a brokerage account that holds multiple securities.  The account ledger can have transactions for all the different securities that are bought and sold.  Is there no way to do this with GNUCash?

Answer (score 5):

You can set up your accounts following the `Custom Accounts Example` in the [documentation](https://www.gnucash.org/docs/v3/C/gnucash-guide/invest_accounts1.html#invest_custom2).

You will have a parent account for the brokerage that has a child account named Cash. Any transfers to/from the brokerage go to this account. Then you add an account for every investment position you have at the brokerage and when you buy/sell stock you transfer money from the Cash account to the position account.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give this a try.  My biggest concern was being able to import a single download from the brokerage, and I think your solution will address this concern.